# How to find the points of intersection of two multivariable functions on their outer bounds?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus, volume

I have two multivariable functions, and I want to calculate where they intersect on the outer bounds of $x$ and $y$ between the graphs of $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$.

The functions are:

$f(x,y)=x^2+4y^6$

$g(x,y)=\sin{(x)}+\frac{1}{5}y+4$

I need to find these intersections in order to calculate the volume under the graph of $f(x,y)$ with a double integral that is limited by $g(x,y)$ on the $z$-axis. I am a beginner regarding multivariable calculus, so can anyone help me with this?

Here is an image of the problem:

[image]

Comment: Hello, welcome to MSE! What do you mean by "limited by $g(x,y)$" ?

Comment: I want to calculate the volume of the function $f(x,y)$ bounded by the function $g(x,y)$ on the $z$-axis. But I still have to determine the limit values for $x$ and $y$.